# how to android playstore download app after get data?

Tags: android, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, dynamic-links

my create dynamic link code

```
Firebase.dynamicLinks.shortLinkAsync {
            link = Uri.parse("https:// ?recommenderCode=" + URLEncoder.encode(MyApplication.prefs.recommenderCode))
            domainUriPrefix = "https:// "
            // Open links with this app on Android
            androidParameters(" ") {
                minimumVersion = 220

                fallbackUrl = Uri.parse("intent://#Intent;scheme=choice;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;category=android.intent.category.BROWSABLE;package= ;S.market_referrer=recommenderCode=" +
                        URLEncoder.encode(MyApplication.prefs.recommenderCode) + ";end;")
                socialMetaTagParameters {
                    title = " "
                    description =  " "
                    imageUrl =  Uri.parse("https:// .ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/ ")
                }
            }

            buildShortDynamicLink()
        }.addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            val shortLink = result.shortLink
            sendMsg = "  \n" + shortLink

        }.addOnFailureListener {
        }
```

get dynamic link code

```
     Firebase.dynamicLinks
                .getDynamicLink(intent)
                .addOnSuccessListener(this) { pendingDynamicLinkData ->
                    // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                    var deepLink: Uri? = null
                    if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                        deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.link
                    }
    
                    if (deepLink != null && deepLink.getBooleanQueryParameter("recommenderCode", false)) {
}
```

manifest intentfilter

```
<activity
            android:name=". .splash.SplashActivity"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:host="A.B.link" android:scheme="http"/>
                <data android:host="A.B.link" android:scheme="https"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

[image]

If you click that link while the app is installed, you can receive the recommender code normally.

However, if you install and run the app through that link, you cannot receive the recommender code.

I want to know what is wrong. If the method is wrong, please let me know at least a keyword. Thank you